# Adding a Next and Previous button to switch tabs

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a form that goes across three different tabs named 'contact-tab' 'questions-tab' 'delivery-tab'. I am trying to add Next and Previous buttons to flick through these tabs. Currently you can click on the tab name to get to that page, But I want to replace this with the next and previous buttons. But i cant seem to crack it.

I have tried various pieces of code from all over. And for some reason none of it works. I have replaced my code with there's completely and still doesn't work. --EDIT--

When i press the button nothing happens, so i am unsure what is happening.

Im not good with JS myself so i couldnt make up a function myself. But i have tried different things from posts. Below is an example of what i have done most recently. I have chopped it all down so it is a minimal reproducible code snippet.

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on("shown.bs.tab", function(e){
            console.log(e.target); // newly activated tab
            console.log(e.relatedTarget); // previous active tab
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        function bootstrapTabControl(){
            var i, items = $('.nav-link'), pane = $('.tab-pane');
            // next
            $('.nexttab').on('click', function(){
                for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                    if($(items[i]).hasClass('active') == true){
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(i < items.length - 1){
                    // for tab
                    $(items[i]).removeClass('active');
                    $(items[i+1]).addClass('active');
                    // for pane
                    $(pane[i]).removeClass('show active');
                    $(pane[i+1]).addClass('show active');
                }

        });
        // Prev
        $('.prevtab').on('click', function(){
            for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                if($(items[i]).hasClass('active') == true){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i != 0){
                // for tab
                $(items[i]).removeClass('active');
                $(items[i-1]).addClass('active');
                // for pane
                $(pane[i]).removeClass('show active');
                $(pane[i-1]).addClass('show active');
            }
        });
}
bootstrapTabControl();
    </script>
```

```html
    <head>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/69362e78c5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <?php require_once __DIR__ . '/header.phtml'; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">   <!--Using a list to create the tabs -->
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#contact-tab" class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab">Contact Details</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#questions-tab" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">Questions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#delivery-tab" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">Delivery Info</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
                <form class="row g-3" action="<?= $data['action'] ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="tab-content">       <!-- This involves the tav content -->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="contact-tab">

                            <div class="row">       <!-- start row here -->
                                <h1>Contact & Site Details</h1>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <label for="site_name" class="form-label">Site Name*</label>
                                    <input type="text"
                                        class="form-control"
                                        id="site_name"
                                        name="site_name"
                                        value="<?= $data['record']['site_name'] ?? '' ?>"
                                        placeholder="Enter Site Name"
                                        required><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button class="nexttab">Next</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="questions-tab">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <h6 for="current_machine">1. What is your Current Machine?</h6>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            class="form-control"
                                            id="current_machine"
                                            name="current_machine"
                                            value="<?= $data['record']['current_machine'] ?? '' ?>"
                                            placeholder="Leave blank if none"><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="delivery-tab">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <h6 for="q7">9. What floor is the Machine(s) going to be located on?</h6>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            class="form-control"
                                            id="q7"
                                            name="q7"
                                            value="<?= $data['record']['q7'] ?? '' ?>"
                                            placeholder="Please enter what floor your machine will be located on"> <br><br>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: If i have done something wrong, Please dont downvote. Let me know the change and ill fix it up asap